# regex rewrite in nginx to match year in the URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, regex

I am trying to write an nginx rewrite directive that redirects a URL like `https://website.com/2018/11/20/dummytext/feed/` to `https://website.com/2018/11/20/dummytext/` (removing the `/feed/` in the end).

I cannot just do a match for `(.*)/feed/` because I do not want to redirect `https://website.com/feed/`.

I've created this regex that matches all posts with /feed/ in the end, which appears to work:
 https://www.regextester.com/?fam=111507

This is what I have in nginx:

```
rewrite "^\b(19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2}\b\/(.*)\/feed\/?$" https://website.com/$1 permanent;
```

The first problem is that it does not appear to work (I have restarted nginx). When I visit a URL like `https://website.com/2018/11/20/dummytext/feed/` I am not redirected anywhere. The second problem is that I'm not sure about this part `https://website.com/$1` and whether it would actually cut the `/feed/` from the URL keeping the rest of the URL as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Nginx supports `\b`, but you only need to use `/` (without a backslash).

You do not need to specify `https://example.com` in the replacement URI if the value remains unchanged. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

In the example in your question, two values are captured (`$1` and `$2`), but only one is used in the replacement URI.

Try:

```
rewrite "^/(19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2}/(.*)/feed/?$" /$1/$2/ permanent;
```

---

You mention that `.*` also matches zero characters, however, `.+` matches *at least* one character. Also, the placement of multiple `/` characters in the pattern can avoid the `/feed` edge condition.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(/.+/)feed/?$ $1 permanent;
```

Comment: Works perfectly!